# Putting an array into a table with SimpleXMLobject using php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Title] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => aa
                )

            [Pubdate] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => aa
                )

            [Link] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => aa
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Title] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => bb
                )

            [Pubdate] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => bb
                )

            [Link] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => bb
                )

        )
```

I want to put this into a table which has (Title, Pubdate, Link) as its columns. I am really confused to how to put it into mysql table when there is `SimpleXMLElement Object and [0]` in the way. If those were not in the way, I would easily be able to put it into the table, but because those are there and I have never seen them before, I am terribly confused.

This is what I have tried:

```
foreach($string as $item){
INSERT into table (Title, Pubdate, Link)VALUES($item->title, $item->pubDate, $item->link)
}
```

FYI this is how I made the array:

```
$string = $con->channel->item;
$table = array();
foreach ($string as $item) {
    $table[] = array(
        'Title' => $item->title,
        'Pubdate' => $item->pubDate,
        'Link' => $item->link
    );
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Putting into table from a complicated array using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32041625/putting-into-table-from-a-complicated-array-using-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just insert that in the database. Implode first the array.

Try this:

```
  $string = $con->channel->item;
  $table = array();
   foreach ($string as $item) {
    $sql = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO table (Title, Pubdate, Link)VALUES('$item->title', '$item->pubDate', '$item->link')";
   );
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, but it says Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in

Comment: When I do echo $title, there seems to be nothing inside the variable

Comment: It says expecting ')' for the line with the second foreach. So I thought that you meant $key -> $val, but then it says cannot access empty property

Comment: Sorry I fixed something. Inside the foreach loop

Comment: It just comes up with Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array if I print_r one of them

Comment: Can you please try to print `$title` again?

Comment: I'm sorry, but still nothing

Comment: Can you try this now? And see your database?

Answer (score 1):

why isnt this working?
what happens when you try it?

```
foreach($string as $item){
INSERT into table (Title, Pubdate, Link)VALUES($item->title, $item->pubDate, $item->link)
}
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING so I put it into $sql and did mysql_query($sql, $db_con);

Comment: obviously, it has to be inside mysql_query otherwise it wont work, unless that was a mistake. but does that query work now?

Comment: What do you mean by that? I'm still a beginner

Comment: in the foreach statement above you have the insert query just like that alone without mysql_query. php isnt going to know what to do with that and sees it as a string. so when you added it into mysql_query that tells php that this is a query. thats what i meant.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this..

```
// output array, to store in database
$result = array();

foreach($table as $key => $simpleXml) {
   $result[$key] = $simpleXml->asXML();
}

// gets your result as a string => you can now insert it into mysql
$dbInsertion = serialize($result);
```